# Java, switch statement: Write command and text message on the same line + object name as a command?

Tags: java, object, command-line, switch-statement, command

I'm complete beginner in Java. In my program, the user is supposed to write the command *message* followed by some text **on the same line** before pressing the return-key, and the program should print the entered text. Is this possible? I aim for something like this:

```
Command> message this is a message!
this is a message!
```

At the moment I'm using a switch statement for all the commands in the program. Right now I have to write "message" then press enter before writing the text.

```
 Command> message
 this is a message!
 this is a message! (output)
```

My code:

```
switch (cmd) {
    //other commands 

      case "message":
                printMessage();
                break;
      default:
        System.out.println("Wrong command!");

}

public void printMessage() {
        String text = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println(text);
    }
```

I also have to include another command in the program, where the user enters the name of an event and the program prints info about said event. 
Is it possible to have an object name as a command?

```
Command> event name
information about event above, if the event exists (output)
```

A switch statement seems to be too limited for this? If that won't work, what other options do I have?

Comment: Are all of your commands entered the same way?

IE: {command} information for the command

Comment: Hint: Use a scanner, read the input, split that and get the message value!

Comment: How do you wish to identify that user stopped typing?

Comment: @Justin.Bell  
I have different commands with different outputs etc. Like add an event/participant, remove them, print results and so on. Can be entered like: command> add participant (the program asks for info about that participant and adds them) all those commands are strings

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Thank you! But I'm not sure I fully understand, I basically just started programming in java. Could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: @Coder I'm sorry but I don't understand the question. At the moment the user's input stops when they press the enter key?

Comment: There you are @Nathalie, feel free to upvote and accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you have a class and that you can at least print a HelloWorld message in the Terminal

so... you will need:

Scanner object so you can read the input given by the user and the Split method from the String class so you can *split* the input **message Hola_World** in 2 parts, the 1st is **message** and the 2nd is **Hola_World**

## Example:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = inputScanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Foo: " + userInput);
    String[] userInputSplitted = userInput.split(" " );
    String fisrtPart = userInputSplitted[0];
    String secondPart = userInputSplitted[1];
    System.out.println("1st Part: " + fisrtPart);
}
```